# push date + time timestamp firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Angular Material in my reactive form and Firestore to store the date and time. Since Angular Material only has Datepicker (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) and not Timepicker I have worked the time in another field, that is, I have two fields.

But this causes me other problems when wanting to filter data by date and time.

My question is, **how can I put and store the date and time in a single firestore field?**

Currently this is what I have:

**components.ts**

```
this.forma = fb.group ({
  fechaInicio: [ '', Validators.required ],
  horaInicio: [ '', Validators.required ],  
});
```

components.html

```
<div class="row">
  <mat-form-field class="col-lg-7 col-6" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Fecha inicio</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Fecha inicio" formControlName="fechaInicio">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="col-lg-5 col-6" appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Hora inicio</mat-label>
    <mat-select placeholder="Hora inicio" formControlName="horaInicio">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let hora of horas" [value]="hora">
      {{ hora }} hrs.
    </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

The result in Firestore is this:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want to call it is fine afaik. Then you can use orderByChild('created').

I also mostly use firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP when setting time

```
ref.child(key).set({
id: itemId,
content: itemContent,
user: uid,
created: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP 
})
```

Comment: I have seen this answer elsewhere? Are you sure of what I am asking?